# Invalid file open mode "IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename:"

Tags: python, python-2.7, curl

Here is the code I am writing in Python:

```
import os
path=os.path.abspath("C:\Users\punagpal\Downloads\curl-7.50.3-win64-mingw\curl-7.50.3-win64-mingw\10.42.129.78_administrator_LogTasks.xml")
f = open(path,'r')
while True:
    text = f.readline()
    if 'name' in text:
        print text
```

But getting the following error:

```
Invalid file open mode "IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename:"
```

Comment: @Selcuk, `path` is not reserved. I messed up the comment so deleted. Is it a good practice to use `path` as a variable ?

Comment: @JaiminAjmeri There is nothing wrong with using it as a variable name, unless you do something like, for example, `from os import path` which is a bad coding practice itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your backslash (`\`) characters:

```
path=os.path.abspath("C:\\Users\\punagpal\\Downloads\\curl-7.50.3-win64-mingw\\curl-7.50.3-win64-mingw\\10.42.129.78_administrator_LogTasks.xml")
```